# C# Write to and read from txt file

Tags: readfile

[image: 1]

Hallo! I have a specific question about my homework - C# window form app.
I enter data in text fields - first name, surname, last name, phone, email and date of birth (the last one is DateTimePicker control). And I save them with a button (
It's not actually saved at this stage, the data just goes to the other page of the app.)

Full names appear in ComboBox in other TabPage. When I select a name, I get the complete information about the person. I do that and it's works.(I'm using arrays).

The task done so far does not store any information. All input is lost when the application is closed.
The other part of the task gives me trouble - a link to an external text file in which the entered data is stored.

I create a text file and save information in it with this code :

```
               private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\data.txt");
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
            {
                txt.Write(Names[k] + "\n" + Phone[k] + "\n" + Email[k] + "\n" + Birthday[k] + "\n");
            }
            txt.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved in data.txt file on drive D!", "Caution!", 0);

        }
```

And the problem is that I can't open and read the file to load the data back into the app.
I need to be able to load the full names in my ComboBox and when I select a name to see all the personal information about that person.
I attach file with my app - page1 and page2 and my text file with store data.
Thanks in advance to everyone who responds :)

And the problem is that I can't open and read the file to load the data back into the app.
I need to be able to load the full names in my ComboBox and when I select a name to see all the personal information about that person.

Comment: _the problem is that I can't open and read the file_ Why not? Are you getting an error? Please add it. Explain exactly what is failing.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it. In the picture I have attached what my text file looks like. I need to open the file and read all the data-line by line. In Combobox "Name" on page "DataSearch"  only people's names should be displayed as a list. And when I choose a name and press the button "ShowPersonalInfo", information about the person should be displayed in Label below - Name, Phone, Email and BirthDate. 
In the text file, these are the first 4 lines - for first person. The next 4 are for the second person and so on. And I don't know how to read file and display data

Comment: Right now your text file uses empty space as a delimiter which is rather bad. Use something like a semicolon to delimit your entries. There is a vast amount of data structures and languages to represent data. An example would be XML or JSON. In your case a simple CSV layout is enough. Just escape the entries, afterwards you can read your file line by line and split each line using your delimiter. I'm not going to tell you ho to do it as it's a home work assignment. Just search Google for how to delimit text and how to split a string in C#

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't know how to read the file. In this case the following tutorial explains the basics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

In the tutorial add your processing code for the contents for the line where the read line is being printed (i.e. `System.Console.WriteLine(line)`).